# UAV 5-Channel Multispectral camera vs. modified RGB camera that resolves NIR

Tags: aerospace-engineering

Looking into purchasing a drone. One has a dedicated 5-channel multispectral camera (Micasense RedEdge) the other has a modified Sony RGB camera that resolves the NIR spectrum. Can someone sum up the pros and cons of each of the above systems? 
Can one filter spectral data taken with a modified camera ?

Here is the manufacturer's description of the modified camera:

We specifically modify our cameras internally and externally to ensure we have technically appropriate 3-band data for either

- NIR vegetation mapping - To use NIR mapping effectively, one
  processes the imagery via algorithms such as NDVI (Normalised
  Difference Vegetation Index), which is a ratio of the NIR band and
  other visible bands.
- Natural colour mapping (RGB)
- Underwater mapping - designed specifically for water penetration
  and underwater bathymetric mapping

All with the SAME modified camera, but simply screwing the appropriate filter onto the lens (we supply the 3 special filters after the camera modification).

To me, it suggests that the "3 bands" are not collected simultaneously as one needs to change filters. Am I correct?

Comment: Could you tell us what your intended use is as this will influence the pros/cons.